# JQuery Datatables Get all "checked" checkboxes over all available pages

Tags: c#, jquery, datatable, datatables

hope you can help me find a solution for this problem I'm having.
Point is I've a view - C# and JQuery with a Datatable- which draws a datatable with thousands of rows.
The datatable is paginated and first column of it, has a checkbox dom object which able the user to check all of them, one or specific ones.
When the user submits the page, I only got the checked items for last page visited by user, and what I need is all the checked rows over all pages available in datatable.
anyone knows how to write a code that returns that?

The code that I already have is this one (returns me only the last page checked rows):

```
var rows_selected = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
        var index = 0;
        rows_selected.each(function () {
            console.log('ListadoActores[' + index + ']'),
            $('<input>', {
                type: 'hidden',
                value: $(this).attr('id').replace('chk', ''),   
                id: $(this).attr('id').replace('chk', ''),
                name: 'ListadoActores[' + index + ']',
                }).appendTo('#GenFileForm');
            index = index + 1;
        });

        $("#GenFileForm").submit();
```

Hope you can help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're using datatables (especially with pre-rendered table that's "split" into pages) then you'll need to use the datatables API (both to set the values on tick and to read them back).  Each time you change the page, datatables completely destroys all the HTML and rebuilds it from its data-store (they're not just set to `display:none`).   So you should never read from the HTML when using datatables.

Comment: I suggest you to use this plugin for checkboxes: https://datatables.net/extensions/select/

Answer (score 0):

As @freedomn-m says, you need to access the Datatables API in order to get all the data.

On your submit, place some code like this:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
var rows = []; 
table.rows().every( function () {
    var d = this.data(); //this will get the data for the row.
    rows.push(d); 
} );
//You can then POST the rows and work with them
```